# Decision on cutting the trees?

Tags: sewer, utilities, tree

I have two big trees in my front yard. Their roots are visible all over the surface in the grounds. I am more concerned about the utility damage (water and sewer) they are eventually going to cause. Is it a good idea to remove both of them and replace with trees which does not grow this big? They are <15 ft away from foundation. They have already cause the concrete damage in the nearby area

[Pics](https://imgur.com/a/6Wfmxsb)

Comment: Get an arborist to give you an expert opinion.

Comment: "Is it a good idea?" isn't a valid question here, as it's primarily an opinion poll. Please revise to ask something more specific and objective.

Comment: What species are these trees? Trees are usually thought to add value to a residental lot if they are not causing excessive damage. What size is the lot (sq ft or fraction of an acre)?

Comment: Ficus and cottonwood are at the top of my "bad tree" list. 15 ft sounds very close, but this question is certainly predicated on the tree species.

Comment: Please post a picture

Answer (score 2):

Most of the damage I'm seeing there is drainage erosion.  Take a look at what's happening on a rainy day, then get some landscaping improvements.  It should be possible to work around the trees.